# According to Advaita is there any difference in the atman before entering maya and after exiting maya?

Tags: atma, advaita

According to Advaita is there any difference in the `atman` before entering maya and after exiting maya?

In other words, does the `atman` gain or lose anything e.g., knowledge?

Does it gain any knowledge after exiting the maya. Is there any change in it's nature?

Does it merge in God or Brahman or something?

I want to know about any change even minute that happens in the `atman`.

By `atman` I mean the "soul" that Vivekananda refers to as being "eternal and ever blissful".

Comment: No, soul doesn't loss or gain anything... because maya can't affect soul.. as soul is non different from Brahman and Brahman is infinite.. hence there is no question of loosing..

Comment: This question would make sense if the word soul is replaced by Jiva. A Jiva thinks himself as an ego when under the influence of Maya. The same Jiva thinks himself as the Atman when he has gone beyond the influence of Maya.

Comment: According to Advaita, there is no Maya, it is just an illusion :). You are always, have always been and will ever remain as you are, the Eternal Brahman. From a relative perspective, there is no beginning to Maya, Maya is sat-asat vilakshana. Avidhya is without beginning, but with an end. All the best :)!

Comment: When you say 'soul' do you mean the jiva or the atman? I think you mean atman, but you should be more specific in your question. The word 'soul' is really a western religious concept which has a different meaning from Hindu concepts.

Comment: @Sai There's a good verse from Gaudapada's Mandukya Karika that illustrates what you're saying: "There is neither dissolution nor creation, none in bondage and none practicing disciplines. There is none seeking Liberation and none liberated. This is the absolute truth." http://www.swamij.com/upanishad-mandukya-karika.htm

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I'm talking about `atman`. `jiva` lives only in the maya. It can't enter or exit maya cos it's already in maya.

Comment: @Sai Can you give an answer quoting the sources that say `atman` never changes especially citing that there is no change in `atman` before and after entering maya or illusion?

Comment: Atman as per advaita is the universal consciousness, the totality of the whole creation or the infinite incomprehensible spirit that is present everywhere, also known as Brahman. Atman never merges in Brahman. Atman IS Brahman. The ultimate reality can be called by 3 different names. These 3 names (Atman, Brahman, Parmatman) can be used interchangebly and they mean the same thing ... Yes some scholars have used the word soul to address this universal spirit, but we should avoid using that word, coz soul or jiva is an entity that transmigrates (changes bodies) but Atman doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Atman is unconditioned, immutable and formless.

Astavakra Samhita:

> सशरीरमिदं विश्वं न किञ्चिदिति निश्र्चितम् ।
>   शुद्धचिन्मात्र आत्मा च तत्कस्मिन् कल्पनाघुना ।।
>
> I have known for certain that the body and the universe are nothing and that
>   the Atman is Pure Consciousness alone. So on what is it now possible to base
>   imagination? **II.19**

Atman neither enters nor exits, neither comes nor goes.

> एकं सर्वगतं व्योम बहिरन्तर्यथा घटे ।
>   नित्यं निरन्तरं ब्रह्म सर्वभूतगणे तथा ।।
>
> As the same all pervading space is inside and outside a jar, so the eternal all pervasive Brahman exists in all things.  **I.20**
>
> नाहं देहो न मे देहो जीवो नाहमहं हि चित् ।
>   अयमेव हि मे बन्ध अासीद् या जीविते स्पृहा ।।
>
> I am not this body, nor have I a body. **I am not Jiva, I am Pure Consciousness.** This indeed was my bondage that I had thirst for life. **II.22**

Comment: Nice references. Can you post Sanskrit versions of these verses. I am interested in knowing, what's translated as "consciousness"?

Comment: @iammilind Have updated the answer.